# Document classification using libsvm in java

Tags: java, svm, libsvm, document-classification, multilabel-classification

I am using libsvm library for document classification of resumes. I have multiple resumes and I need to classify them. Do I need multilabel classification OR multiclass classification in this case. Which above option should I consider and also please suggest a way to do it?

Comment: @severian .. could you please suggest ?

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is not straight forward, In order to develop such system you need to come up with several steps, as an Example :

1. You need a data set of different types of documents (various type of resumes)
2. Then you need to identify what kind of features that can be use to separate them(how do you going to distinguish them, based on what (ex, resume length, count of word, content of resume header, etc))
3. Then you need to prepare sets of feature vectors in order to train the SVM. (if you need to classify only relevant and irrelevant resumes, this will be two classes. If there are more than two classes , this will be multi-class and LibSVM supports multi-class)
4. When training, you need to perform scaling, cross validation in order to increse the accuracy ([read here](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) )
5. You need to complete above steps in order to make  successful prediction.